# How to solve IE10 issue for my code

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Here is my code through which i am not able to display content using IE10 while its displaying in all IE9,IE8,IE7

```
// Clear the Table Body before insert the rows

this.V_Profile = function(value) {

    var tbl = new NG_ConfTable();

    tbl.addCaptionRow("Profile Definition");

    tbl.addCaptionRow(this.V_ProfileDef(value));

    tbl.addCaptionRow("&nbsp;");



    tbl.addCaptionRow("Client Authentication");

    //tbl.addCaptionRow(new V_AuthSettings(value));

    tbl.addCaptionRow(new V_AuthSettings(value, {networkAuthChangeAction : this.viewClientAuthSetting}));

    tbl.addCaptionRow("&nbsp;");



    //var clientForm = Element.wrap(this.V_ClientAuth(value), "form", {"id" : "clientAuthSetting"});

    tbl.addCaptionRow("Authentication Settings");

    tbl.addCaptionRow(this.V_ClientAuth(value), "clientAuth");

    tbl.addCaptionRow("&nbsp;");



    tbl.addCaptionRow("Wireless QoS");

    tbl.addCaptionRow(this.V_Qos(value));



    var form = Element.wrap(tbl, "form", {"id" : value["#"]});



    formChangeAction(form, function(){

        buttonPanel.get("cancel").enable(true);

    });



    return form;

}.bind(this);           

// Insert the Row Element
```

the above code working for all browser not in IE10 so i am adding the extra piece of code into that is that correct plz suggest me to work in IE10.

Comment: What is `this`, what is its `tableBody` property, what is that `update` method?

Comment: using tableBody i am creating    this.tableBody = new Element("TBODY", {id: this.id+'-body'}); 

    this.insert(this.tableBody); then update method i am using to update before insert the record

Comment: Are you creating tbody every time you need to update UI? In this case you'll get invalid DOM structure and it's good that IE does not tolerate it.

Comment: I've never heard of an `update` method on [`<tbody>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableSectionElement). Are you using [the one](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/update/) from [tag:prototypejs]? Then please indicate that in your question.

Comment: Yes i am using prototypejs...and using tbody to update UI everytime

Comment: You don't get me. You creating new tbody element. Does this.insert removes the old one or just append one more tbody to table? Multiple tbody tags in one table is invalid structure.

Answer (score 0):

Could http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-update-all.html be useful? This works on ie8, I hope to have understand your needs.